# Cancel a transaction or part of a transaction before commit?

Tags: sqlite, commit

I have a long transaction that I have began using `BEGIN`, and I made a mistake about 3 lines prior to the last line.  Is there a way to null that line?

Here's an example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE purchase(id integer PRIMARY KEY, purchasePrice integer CHECK(purchasePrice>0), customer text);
INSERT INTO purchase(purchasePrice, customer) VALUES(1200, "Jerome");
INSERT INTO purchase(purchasePrice, customer) VALUES(200, "Jeffery");
INSERT INTO purchase(purchasePrice, customer) VALUES(40, "Craig");
INSERT INTO purchase(purchasePrice, customer) VALUES(1640, "Donovan");
INSERT INTO purchase(purchasePrice, customer) VALUES(100, "Williams");
INSERT INTO purchase(purchasePrice, customer) VALUES(50, "Matsushi");
INSERT INTO purchase(purchasePrice, customer) VALUES(150, "Xhao");
INSERT INTO purchase(purchasePrice, customer) VALUES(250, "Dilberta");
INSERT INTO purchase(purchasePrice, customer) VALUES(840, "Brow"); //Supposed to be 9440,"Brown"
INSERT INTO purchase(purchasePrice, customer) VALUES(440, "DarkBrown");
INSERT INTO purchase(purchasePrice, customer) VALUES(20, "Black");
COMMIT;
```

I do understand that I can later update the affected row.

Another example situation:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Movies(MId integer primary key autoincrement, Title text);
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES(1,'Capote');
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES(2,'Scent of a woman');
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES(3,'Stigmata');
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES(4,'Exorcist');
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES(5,'Hamsun');
//Changed my mind and want to name the table "movie" and  name the columns "m_id" and "title".
```

So, I'm wondering a) how to cancel; and b) is it possible to go up a few lines, and if so, how?

Comment: @MitchWheat No it isn't.  It's called `ALTER COLUMN`, and that feature doesn't exist in sqlite3.  It reduces the workload a great deal to cancel prior to commit.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Comment: @MitchWheat If that's an answer, put it in the answers section.  You know it isn't an answer and doesn't address this question at all.  Why do you want to be  flagged?

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes it does.  You 'BEGIN' a transaction and 'COMMIT' a transaction; therefore, you should be able to 'STOP' or 'CANCEL' the transaction.

Comment: it's generally called ROLLBACK

Comment: @MitchWheat Okay, then it's called ROLLBACK--a feature I didn't know about; thus, the question.  And since you can answer the question in such a cut-and-dry way, it must make sense.  In the first scenario, UPDATE would make more sense than ROLLBACK because ROLLBACK would remove all inserts to update only one entry.

Comment: @MitchWheat Another reason I asked is because google's top hit for keyword: 'SQLITE3 TUTORIAL', http://zetcode.com/databases/sqlitetutorial/, does not cover ROLLBACK, and my searches 'cancel', 'stop', 'opposite of commit' did not yield a page on ROLLBACK.

Comment: @MitchWheat Sorry, man.  I didn't mean to come off as rude.  I just cannot understand.  This isn't the first place I go.  I posted the question in chats and on forums, asked a friend who is also studying a tutorial, and did several google searches.  This seems like a perfectly good manpage question without duplicates that is easy to answer.  I think it's a great question, but as soon as I post it my reputation goes down.  Actually, correlations like 'cancel; rollback (synonyms)' need to be recorded somewhere, to aid learning.

Comment: No mention of rollback in the official SQLITE3 FAQ.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 It might not be on the FAQ, but it's covered clearly at the [SQLite.org SQL Page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html), where BEGIN, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK TRANSACTION feature prominently, and all three links take you to the same page [that covers all three statements](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Comment: @rob thanks.  I hadn't seen those pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had created [savepoints](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html), you would be able to roll back part of the transaction. (But that would be even more typing.)

When you are doing many changes, it is a good idea to write all the SQL commands into a text file before you execute them.

Answer (score 0):

The `ROLLBACK` feature cancels the complete transaction.  I have not found a way to go back line-by-line, so the `UPDATE` or `ALTER` commands can be used for tables or fields/rows, respectively.